# Where to enter the string in "evaluate simple math expression"

Tags: java, android, string, math

I'm currently working on a school project in Android. I've written a code which generates a random equation, like 8+4/2, everytime you press a button on the screen and now I want to evaluate the result of the equation which is stored in a String. As there is no simple command to evaluate the result of a simple math expression allready implemented in Android Studio, I found a code here on Stackoverflow.com which evaluates the math expression from a string. (Here is the link to this post: [How to evaluate a math expression given in string form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form) )

Here is the code to evaluate the math expression:

```
public static double eval(final String str) {
return new Object() {
    int pos = -1, ch;

    void nextChar() {
        ch = (++pos < str.length()) ? str.charAt(pos) : -1;
    }

    boolean eat(int charToEat) {
        while (ch == ' ') nextChar();
        if (ch == charToEat) {
            nextChar();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    double parse() {
        nextChar();
        double x = parseExpression();
        if (pos < str.length()) throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected: " + (char)ch);
        return x;
    }

    // Grammar:
    // expression = term | expression `+` term | expression `-` term
    // term = factor | term `*` factor | term `/` factor
    // factor = `+` factor | `-` factor | `(` expression `)`
    //        | number | functionName factor | factor `^` factor

    double parseExpression() {
        double x = parseTerm();
        for (;;) {
            if      (eat('+')) x += parseTerm(); // addition
            else if (eat('-')) x -= parseTerm(); // subtraction
            else return x;
        }
    }

    double parseTerm() {
        double x = parseFactor();
        for (;;) {
            if      (eat('*')) x *= parseFactor(); // multiplication
            else if (eat('/')) x /= parseFactor(); // division
            else return x;
        }
    }

    double parseFactor() {
        if (eat('+')) return parseFactor(); // unary plus
        if (eat('-')) return -parseFactor(); // unary minus

        double x;
        int startPos = this.pos;
        if (eat('(')) { // parentheses
            x = parseExpression();
            eat(')');
        } else if ((ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') || ch == '.') { // numbers
            while ((ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') || ch == '.') nextChar();
            x = Double.parseDouble(str.substring(startPos, this.pos));
        } else if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') { // functions
            while (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') nextChar();
            String func = str.substring(startPos, this.pos);
            x = parseFactor();
            if (func.equals("sqrt")) x = Math.sqrt(x);
            else if (func.equals("sin")) x = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(x));
            else if (func.equals("cos")) x = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(x));
            else if (func.equals("tan")) x = Math.tan(Math.toRadians(x));
            else throw new RuntimeException("Unknown function: " + func);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected: " + (char)ch);
        }

        if (eat('^')) x = Math.pow(x, parseFactor()); // exponentiation

        return x;
    }
}.parse();
}
```

Where in the code above do I have to enter my String with my equation in it? I really don't know where to put it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass your `String` to the `eval` function like this:

```
String myEquation = "8+4/2";
double answer = eval(myEquation);
```

Comment: ^^ the `String myEquation = "8+4/2";
double answer = eval(myEquation);`

Comment: My code example is to give you an idea but you'll have to bridge the gap yourself. Your code above is just the eval function. You need to get your string from wherever you want (e.g. from a text field) and then call the eval function with that string. You only posted code for the eval function and since I can't see the rest of your code I can't say exactly where to put it. But, I think you can take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method like this

```
class YourMathClass {
    public static double eval(final String str) { ....
    }
}
```

And then in your application

```
 double result = YourMathClass.eval("8+4/2");
```

or

```
 String equation = "8+4/2"; //valid equation
 double result = YourMathClass.eval(equation);
```

if you are using this method inside the class where you need it then use @jenglert's answer